# Setup Ruby app on cPanel shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpanel

What I'm trying to do is to deploy a Ruby On Rails app on cPanel with shared hosting. I'm new to cPanel or anything to do with web hosting. Following the guides I managed to upload the app but when I run it, it gives me following Passenger error:

`cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`

Any response is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

What I have done so far: 
[cPanel's Setup Ruby App function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7eQH.png)

Answer (score 1):

you need to install bundler as a module

Comment: Deleted an older comment for misreading an error. Done installing bundler but now it gives me a new Passenger error: `You have requested: mysql2 < 0.5, >= 0.3.13 The bundle currently has mysql2 locked at 0.4.4. Try running `bundle update mysql2` (Bundler::GemNotFound)` . Perhaps I also need to add mysql2 as a module? Also it tells me to run `bundle install`. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: yes, try to add mysql2 as a module and try to execute "bundle install"

Comment: While trying to add mysql2 as a module the cPanel stops responding after a while and the page goes blank. Also when I run `bundle install` on Execute Command field it gives me an error: `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`.

Comment: Create a "Gemfile" at your Rails root with the default contentent. You can get the default content at 'https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-1-default-files'. Also add your mysql2-gem.

Comment: Update. Changed mysql2 version in my Gemfile to 0.4.4 from < 0.5, >= 0.3.13 and it looks like solved later error. Now it gives me a Passenger error: `Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.2.5.1) ruby'` though. I'm trying to add Rails as a module on a cPanel but again it stops responding in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hosting service has upgraded their cpanel software 
(this should be the case since upgrading implies security fixes).
As of 18 September 2017 Cpanel version 66 supports Ruby 2.2.7 and Rails 4.1.0 this is the highest version to date in the "Ruby Setup App" create a Ruby 2.2 Environment.

To install rails you need to use the module setup ruby app
Then execute the command: gem install rails -v 4.1.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc

This should install rails, you're not going to get a later version than rails 4.1.0.  Rails 3 breaks cpanel so don't try it.

cpanel might hang on this one, but it seems to deploy all the gems correctly. Wait a bit and then refresh - you should have rails installed

Answer (score 0):

As of 18 September 2017
Cpanel version 66 supports Ruby 2.2.7 and Rails 4.1.0 this is the highest version to date in the "Ruby Setup App" create a Ruby 2.2 Environment.

gem install rails -v 4.1.0